# How do I make my object not leave a trail while moving in Pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV8vP.png) Okay so I am not able to figure out how to delete the previous render of the object every frame from screen so as to not leave a trail behind, in other words I want the object to have the appearance of Movement rather than leaving a bunch of red squares behind it. Image has been inserted for understanding what I mean by "leaving a trail" The following is my code:-

```
import pygame
import random

WIDTH = 1000
ROWS = 25
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,WIDTH))
pygame.display.set_caption("Particle Physics")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

RED = (255, 0, 0)
GRAVITY = 2
wid = 5

class Square:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,color,vel_x,vel_y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.velx = vel_x
        self.vely = vel_y

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.width))

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.velx
        self.y += self.vely
        self.vely += GRAVITY[enter image description here][1]    


def particles():
    pass

def main():
    run = True
    a,b = 500,300
    c = random.randint(-20,20)
    d = random.randint(-50,0)
    square = Square(a,b,wid, RED, c, d)

    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        square.move()
        square.draw()

        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.delay(100)
        #clock.tick(60)

    pygame.quit()

main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the main function add the set background color at the start so as to delete the previous frames.

```
def main()
   ...
   while run
     ....
     screen.fill((255,255,255))
     ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much ,really appreciate your help

Comment: Clearing the screen at the start of each frame is way too slow. The newbie tutorial at `https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/newbieguide.html` explains how to only update the rectangle containing the previous sprite position (see the section **Dirty Rect Animation**)

Comment: @SiddharthAgrawal How do i do that? I'm new to this, sorry

Comment: There is a tick mark next to my answer. Click it and it will turn green. I also did not know about this when I first joined